# Add Startup App menu broken

Tags: gtk, user-interface

My Add Startup App menu is broken. I can still type and use the keyboard to select, but I can't see any of the results.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

EDIT: 
Looks like the app Franz may be the culprit:

[image]

Comment: That sounds like a very concrete bug, I would suggest opening an issue in the Applications settings plug: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-applications
If you scroll down in that list, is there a very long item in there? That's could be the cause of why it's stretched like that.

Comment: Yes that's indeed the case. Looks like Franz has a veery long description. Anyway, there should be horizontal scrolling in this case.

Comment: I've opened a pull request: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-applications/pull/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-applications/pull/15
I don't know whether it will be released in Loki.